# Mercurial - multiple heads blocking push because named branch was done mid-stream

Tags: mercurial

I had cloned the repository from the default (only) branch.  Did a lot of work on it with many commits.  I finally wanted to push the current changes as a separate development stream back to the repository. So I did a hg branch 8-2-.  Pulled what was currently on the repository (still only the default branch).  Merged the changes to my stuff.
Now, when I attempt to do hg push --new-branch, I still get the multiple heads warning:

> abort: push creates new remote head 57550f12d0f6! (did you forget to
>   merge? use push -f to force)

Did a hg heads:

> changeset:   132:8ab701e45e38 branch:      8-2- tag:         tip
>   parent:      131:3f2c30e8396d parent:      129:a45e28d1ef1b user:
>   Vance Neff  date:        Mon Aug 06 14:55:14
>   2012 -0400 summary:     merge unexpected head
>
> changeset:   129:a45e28d1ef1b user:        Vance Neff
>    date:        Thu Aug 02 14:15:08 2012 -0400
>   summary:     Added tag 8-1-29 for changeset 7d88ac157486
>
> changeset:   113:57550f12d0f6 user:        Vance Neff
>    date:        Thu Aug 02 18:29:32 2012 -0400
>   summary:     Added tag 8-2-29 for changeset 4ab1691d7120

I see that the offending head is the last commit just before I did the hg branch 8-2-, changeset 113.

How do I resolve this?  Note: I have read all the warnings concerning using named branched here.  Too late.

Thanks Vance

Answer (score 1):

I can’t see exactly what you did there and the current state of your repository, but it looks like you need to merge the two changesets on `default` together.

```
hg update 129
hg merge 113
hg commit -m "merge"
```

After that you will only have one head on `default` again and all is well.

Alternatively, you can use the `strip` command to remove all your (un-pushed) changes that went wrong. Then you can redo them. Note, make sure only to strip changesets appearing in `hg outgoing` so that you don’t remove any public changesets.

Tip: when I don’t feel confident about a command I’m about to run, I usually make a clone or copy of the repository before executing it, so that I can always easily revert back to the original state. One of the blessings of DVCS :).

Comment: If I do the suggested update, merge & commit.  I should be able to do a 
hg push --branch branchname --new-branch branchname

And I just have to be sure that I ALWAYS specify "-branch branchname" whenever I push from this repository in order to avoid changes to the released (default branch) version.

Comment: As a follow up, I then did hg update branchname, and then a hg merge 133 to retrieve the changes I made in the new development stream.  Note that when I indicated branchname, I actually used "8-2-".  Now I'm good to "hg push --branch 8-2- --new-branch 8-2-" or I could use "hg push --branch . --new-branch 8-2-".